# How change PowerPoint zoom level with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I'm using AppleScript to show PowerPoint slides as part of a manual testing/inspection step for code that generates the slides.

It's all working nicely, but I can't work out how to tell PowerPoint to zoom to 'fit' or 188% in my case.

`set the zoom of the active window to 185` does nothing.

How do I get a reference to the property of interest here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on **Microsoft Office 2016**, tested on Version 15.27:

```
-- Example: Set zoom to 188% --
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    tell active window to set zoom of its view to 188
end tell

-- Example: Set zoom to fit --
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    tell active window to set zoom to fit of its view to true
end tell
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! :)

Comment: Also tested and works on Microsoft PowerPoint 2011 v14.7.7 (Mac)